# How would I add validation to my Datepicker input by clicking a button

Tags: angular

I'm just starting to learn Angular 6 and am stuck on an issue involving applying a validation message to my datepicker input if empty. I'm hoping to achieve this if a user clicks the submit button and if they forget to pick a date, a validation message would show to say "Please enter a date." Again, I'm very new to this and appreciate the feedback - I've pasted my code so far. Thank you!

```
  <!-- Datepicker code-->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xl-9 col-lg-8">
                <ng-container *ngIf="isLoggedIn()">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" method="get">
                        <fieldset>
                            <div class="form-group row mb">
                                <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Date Range</label>
                                <div class="col-md-9">

                                    <!-- The code below is for a date range (picks two dates) -->
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control hasDatepicker" name='dateSelected' id="dateSelected" value=""  data-validation="dateSelected" data-validation-format="mm/dd/yyyy" #drp="bsDaterangepicker" bsDaterangepicker
                                        [bsConfig]="bsConfig" (bsValueChange)="onChangeDates($event)" required>

                                        <ng-container *ngIf=".invalid && (dateSelected.dirty || dateSelected.touched)"
                                        class="alert alert-danger">
                                            <div *ngIf="dateSelected.errors.required">
                                                Name is required.
                                            </div>
                                        </ng-container>

                                    </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="searchForResults()">Submit</button>
                </ng-container>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using reactive forms to do this instead of template form approach.
Reactive form enables you add the necessary logic you need while implementing your form group and form control.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this below, Use ngSubmit and move button inside form

```
<form class="form-horizontal" #anyForm="ngForm" name="formExample" (ngSubmit)="searchForResults()">
                    <fieldset>
                        <div class="form-group row mb">
                            <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Date Range</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">

                                        <!-- The code below is for a date range (picks two dates) -->
                                        <input required class="form-control" type="text"  name='dateSelected' id="dateSelected" [(ngModel)]="model.dateSelected" #dateSelected="ngModel" />

  <div [hidden]="dateSelected.valid || dateSelected.pristine"class="alert alert-danger">
      Date is required
</div>
   </div>
    </div>
    </fieldset>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" >Submit</button>
                        </form>
```